# Accelerated C++ istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& hw)

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand one of the functions in the book Accelerated C++.

On page 57 of that book, I see the following function:

```
istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& hw)
{
    if (in) {
        // get rid of previous contents
        hw.clear();

        // read homework grades
        double x;
        while ( in >> x) {
            hw.push_back(x);

            // clear the stream so that input will work for the next student
            in.clear();
        }
        return in;
    }
}
```

What I do not understand is, **what is the point of returning `in` from this function.  How does the function know when the input ends?** Can anyone help me understand this please? I read the book but I it left me asking for more clarification so that I understand this better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a missing `}` in your code. I've already commented out the declaration of `x`...

Answer (score 0):

In `Accelerated C++` it also says:

> Notice that read_hw returns in. Moreover, it does so as a reference.
>   In effect, we are saying that we were given an object, which we are
>   not going to copy, and we will return that same object, again without
>   copying it. Returning the stream allows our caller to write.

To put it in my words, every time you write a number and hit enter, the stream returns, and this function is called.

The user hitting the enter signals the end of stream.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, can you guide me as to what i should do. Do i need to remove the quote or the link or something?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for returning the input stream is so that the caller can chain commands doing other operations on the stream if they want to.

The function knows the input has ended because the stream object returned by the `>>` operator is implicitly converted to a boolean saying whether the read operation in the `while` conditional has succeeded.